# Leaflet + geojson datas

Tags: leaflet

I'm working on a project using Leaflet. For this project I've created an interface to draw all the roofs of a large city as polygons. A lot of scripts calculate the surfaces, the addresses, the orientation and so on... I'll store each roof's datas in a geojson file (or files). We expect to get about 10 000 roofs or more. I don't know if Leaflet displays only visibles polygons depending window's boundaries or if all the polygons are drawn, and my problem is to find the better way to do this storage.

1. In **one** geojson file. It may be a problem because the 10 000 roofs are computed in the same time and waiting for polygons loading may be very boring for users.
2. In separated geojson files: for each roof I can approximatively calculate the coordinates of its center and put this roof in the right geojson file depending the lat/lng. By this way I can create (say 20 or 50) differents geojson files and call the right one depending boundaries. Then the question is: to create all the polygons, is it better to call the 6 (or 8 or 10) geojson usefull files for the area on screen, or is it better to create a new dynamic geojson file?
3. All the roof's datas are stored in a database or in a XML file and I have to detect boundaries and automatically create a dynamic geojson file. But each time user scroll or darg or zoom the map I'm supposed to recreate this unique geojson file...

Do you ever have a similar problem to solve and how do you solve it ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second scenario is the most robust, you need tiled GeoJSON tiles. Have a look at Leaflet Plugins. There is one called [TileLayer.GeoJSON](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/). Some links on how to create these tiles are on [OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles).

Comment: Bryan McBride provides a solution on https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON